# Can I convert bool in model to yes/no in a QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

I have a database with a column value 0/1.

I use QSqlRelationalTableModel for showing data to widget.

Is it possible to show Yes for 1 and No for 0 in a QComoboBox?
And also, when I select yes/no, it should save to DB as 1/0.

Can I do something with `setData()` and `getData()` functions? Could someone give a clue how to start?

**UPDATE:**

```
    mpCountryModel->setTable("CountryMaster");
    mpCountryModel->select();

    ui->comboBox->setModel(mpCountryModel);
    ui->comboBox->setModelColumn(5);
```

As in column 5 has value 0 or 1, the same will display 0 and 1, right?

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: could you tell how to start with

Comment: `if (column value) "yes" else "no"` .....

Comment: @Abin Have you tried overriding `QVariant data(..)`? I remember doing this a while ago. I think you have to check the column and role (may be `EditRole` for controls) and return `Yes/No` as per the value.

Answer (score 0):

A complete example in [literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) style follows. Let's start with a header and common constants:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/proxy-combo-31995345
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtSql>

const QString kYes = QStringLiteral("Yes");
const QString kNo = QStringLiteral("No");
```

First of all, you have to translate the data from the database into form suitable for display and editing. For display, you need to map 0->No and 1->Yes. For editing, you need to map 0->false and 1->true so that the combo box editor is used. You need a proxy model:

```
/// Maps a given column from {0,1} to {false, true} for editing and {kNo, kYes} for display
class BoolProxy : public QIdentityProxyModel {
    int m_column;
public:
    BoolProxy(int column, QObject * parent = nullptr) :
        QIdentityProxyModel{parent}, m_column{column} {}
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const override {
        auto val = QIdentityProxyModel::data(index, role);
        if (index.column() != m_column) return val;
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole) {
            if (val.toInt() == 0) {
                if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) return kNo;
                return false;
            } else {
                if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) return kYes;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
    bool setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role) override {
        auto val = value;
        if (index.column() == m_column && role == Qt::EditRole)
            val = val.toBool() ? 1 : 0;
        return QIdentityProxyModel::setData(index, val, role);
    }
};
```

Secondly, you need to modify the entries displayed by the boolean combo box editor. By default they are "True" and "False". You need to change them to "Yes" and "No", respectively:

```
class YesNoDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        auto ed = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
        auto combo = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(ed);
        combo->setItemText(0, kNo);
        combo->setItemText(1, kYes);
        return ed;
    }
};
```

Let's put these all together:

[image: screenshot of the example]

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    if (! db.open()) return 1;
    db.exec("create table example (name text, inuse numeric);");
    db.exec("insert into example (name, inuse) values "
            "('Zaphod', 0), ('Beeblebrox', 1);");

    QSqlTableModel model;
    model.setTable("example");
    model.select();

    BoolProxy proxy{1};
    proxy.setSourceModel(&model);

    QTableView ui;
    YesNoDelegate delegate;
    ui.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, &delegate);
    ui.setModel(&proxy);
    ui.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I get only 1 and 2 in my combobox

Answer (score 0):

Is this any good?. This worked for me.

```
TableModel* model = new TableModel(this);
ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
ui->comboBox->setModelColumn(TableModel::BoolColumn);
```

//------------- tablemodel.h --------------------

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const;

int columnCount(const QModelIndex& ) const
{
    return 2;
}

int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parentIndex) const
{
    return parentIndex.isValid() ? 0 : 2;
}
```

//--------------------- tablemodel.cpp ----------------

```
QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
   if (!index.isValid() || index.row() > 2) {
      return QVariant();
   }

switch (role) {
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
    case Qt::EditRole:
        if (index.column() == 0)
            return tr("Column %1").arg(index.column());
        else
            if (index.row() % 2 == 0)
                return "Yes";
            else
                return "No";
    default:
        break;
}
return QVariant();
}
```