# Add virtual column to Qt SQL model using a proxy

Tags: c++, qt

I display an SQL table in a view using a **QSqlTableModel**.

I want to display an additional status column based on the row data, for that I use a custom **QIdentityProxyModel** where I increase the *columnCount* and return *data* for that new virtual column which does not exist in the **QSqlTableModel**.

```
int MyProxyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    return sourceModel() ? (sourceModel()->columnCount() + 1) : 0;
}

QVariant MyProxyModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (section == columnCount()-1 && 
        orientation == Qt::Horizontal &&
        role == Qt::DisplayRole) 
    {
        return tr("MyHeader");
    }

    return QIdentityProxyModel::headerData(section, orientation, role);
}

QVariant MyProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex, int role) const
{
    qDebug() << "data " << proxyIndex.row() << proxyIndex.column(); 
    // ...never called for my extra column (== columnCount()-1)

    if (proxyIndex.column() == columnCount()-1 && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QString("I am virtual");

    return QIdentityProxyModel::data(proxyIndex, role);
}
```

***Edit:*** I changed the code for something more simple regarding to the comments. I still have the same problem.

My problem is that the view never asks data for my virtual column, it calls *data()* for all other columns of the actual SQL table but not the last virtual one, what have I missed ?
Also, the header data is working well for my extra column, the problem is only with the data. The view draws the extra column, but content is empty (even alternating row background is not painted).
Thx !

Comment: what is the value of `m_mySqlTableColumnCount`?

Comment: try implementing `columnCount` to `return QIdentityProxyModel::columnCount()+1;`, that way you can avoid errors from assigning erroneous values to your `m_mySqlTableColumnCount`.

Comment: @Mike That's what I did at first but some reason my app crashed with an infinite stack of calls to `columnCount`. I made sure my value is correct using the `sourceModelChanged` signal, I checked the value and it's fine, my column count returns the good value.

Comment: Also my header is working well, so I don't understand why the column content does not.

Comment: This question cannot be answered and is off topic without you providing a complete test case that reproduces the issue. **The code that you show is correct - I can get it to work without any changes**. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31998748/1329652) for an example of a self-contained test case for a proxy and a database model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view needs to get the `QModelIndex` objects for the virtual column, so I also needed to override the `index` function in the proxy :

```
QModelIndex MyProxyModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (column == columnCount()-1)
        return createIndex(row, column);

    return QIdentityProxyModel::index(row, column);
}
```

I didn't mind the parent because I only have a table (from database), though I do not know how it could be dealt with if needed because createIndex does not allow to specify a parent.

Comment: The problem with the identity proxy model, is it assumes the number of columns and rows are the same of the underlying model. So, for example, if you don't reimplement `insertColumn`, or `sibling`, or any method that receives a row row/column integers, it directly calls the `sourceModel()` equivalent method, without calling first to `mapToSource`, for example. In your case, it works fine because your extra column is the last one, but in my case, my virtual column is the first one and I had to reimplement almost every method. And how knows if you want to use persistent indexes for your model.

Answer (score 2):

The `m_mySqlTableColumnCount` member is unnecessary. You'd have to ensure it's always correct by listening to the source model's signals that update the column count. Alas, it's unnecessary. You want to pass the column count request through to the source model:

```
int MyProxyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    return sourceModel() ? (QIdentityProxyModel::columnCount() + 1) : 0;
}
```

Then:

```
QVariant MyProxyModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (section == columnCount()-1 && 
        orientation == Qt::Horizontal &&
        role == Qt::DisplayRole) 
    {
        return tr("MyHeader");
    }    
    return QIdentityProxyModel::headerData(section, orientation, role);
}

QVariant MyProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex, int role) const
{
    if (proxyIndex.column() == columnCount()-1) {
      qDebug() << proxyIndex.row() << proxyIndex.column();
      ...
    }
    return QIdentityProxyModel::data(proxyIndex, role);
}
```

Comment: I tried this at first but it leads to a crash with a huge stack of calls to `columnCount()`. I didn't find why, but replacing by `return sourceModel() ? (sourceModel()->columnCount() + 1) : 0;` works fine, thx ! It's still not my problem here, I was updating the m_mySqlTableColumnCount correctly anyway.