# Qt QSortfilterproxy model virtual column

Tags: qt, qtsql, qsqltablemodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

A related question has been asked by [ymoreau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6165833/ymoreau) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492264/add-virtual-column-to-qt-sql-model-using-a-proxy) - but there is no decisive solution. I have subclassed [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details) with the purpose to display some data in the virtual column on addition to [QSqlRelationalTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlrelationaltablemodel.html#details) (sourceModel) whose data is from MYSQL database.

Below is my code:

```
class vModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit vModel(QObject *parent): QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
}
virtual QModelIndex index(int row, int column) const
 {
     if(column >= columnCount()-1){
         return createIndex(row,column);
     }
     else
         return QSortFilterProxyModel::index(row, column);
 }
virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return sourceModel() ? (sourceModel()->columnCount() + 1) : 0;
}
virtual bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int    role = Qt::EditRole)
{
    if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole)
    {
        QSortFilterProxyModel::setData(index,value,role);
        emit dataChanged(index,index);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
virtual QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    int amtCol = columnCount()-1;
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal
            && section == amtCol
            && role == Qt::DisplayRole){
        return QString("Amount");
    }
    else
        return QSortFilterProxyModel::headerData(section, orientation, role);
}

virtual QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const {
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    return QModelIndex();
}
virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    int amtCol = columnCount()-1;

    if(index.column() == amtCol ){
        if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
            return QSortFilterProxyModel::data(index, role);
        else{
            QString val = QString("Amount Index(%1,%2)").arg(index.row()).arg(index.column());
            return val;
        }
    }
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::data(index, role);
}
virtual QModelIndex mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &source) const
{
    return index(source.row(), source.column());
}

virtual QModelIndex mapToSource(const QModelIndex &proxy) const
{
    return (sourceModel()&&proxy.isValid())
        ? sourceModel()->index(proxy.row(), proxy.column(), proxy.parent())
        : QModelIndex();
}
protected:
Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = QSortFilterProxyModel::flags(index);
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsSelectable |  Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
    }
    return flags;
}
};
```

The view draws the extra column with correct header as I specified, but the content is empty even alternating row background is not painted. The model returns the correct data when I query the extra column indexes.The delegates returns false when I check the validity of any index in the virtual column yet the my subclassed model returns true.

Where's my problem...Is it the model or the delegates? Is there any additional function that I need to include?

Comment: Why do not you use QIdentityProxyModel instead of QSortFilterProxyModel?

Comment: I used QIdentityProxyModel but but I received the same result

Comment: What information do you want that new column to show?

Comment: In the data function...I have indicated what I wanted to display

Comment: if you use a proxy model you will lose certain QSqlRelationalTableModel functionalities like using QSqlRelationalDelegate.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc but I have tried to use QIdentityProxyModel again: I get a crash at the MapToSource and MapFromSource Functions pointing to my return lines.... When I remove the two functions I get the same result as before

Answer (score -1):

Subclassing the Sourcemodel yielded my expectations so easily. I believe QIdentityProxyModel or any other proxy can do the same task but you have to man-handle so many issues. My Sourcemodel (the QSqlRelationalTableModel) responds to data changes (calculated values in more than 4 virtual columns) and communicates with the default relational-delegate so easily.

If there's away to make proxymodels do this task, I still welcome those suggestions. Am using Qt5.9